# Change Skype Button img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skype

I am using https://www.skype.com/ru/developer/create-contactme-buttons/ functionality. I want to change ONLY image of skype button. I tried changing the css property "content", but it doesn't work for Mozilla browser. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: For img into div with id Skype, i added property: #Skype img{
      content: url('img/icons/Skype.svg') !important;
     }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use skype-uri.js with personalized buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054167/how-can-i-use-skype-uri-js-with-personalized-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because Skype's script loads it as an iFrame. Below is a source code confirmation.

And you can read more about why it is like that on this post:

[Override body style for content in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe)

There are other ways to it like mentioned here:
[How can I use skype-uri.js with personalized buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054167/how-can-i-use-skype-uri-js-with-personalized-buttons)

[image]

Comment: But change css property content work in all browsers, except Mozilla.